# How would I add an image to an html page using a js case/switch function?

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

I have this code block:

```
switch (type) {
 case 'a':
  return 'option 1';
 case 'b':
  return 'option 2';
 case 'c':
  return 'option 3';
 default:
  return '';
}
```

I need it however needs to display a picture. Is there a way of doing something like:

```
switch(type){
 case 'a':
  return <img scr="img1">;
 case 'b':
  return <img scr="img1">;
ect...
```

Comment: `<img scr="img1">` is not a valid expression in Javascript. You could `return '<img scr="img1">'` (note the single quotes around the expression, making it a string).

Answer (score 2):

```
<input id="myInput" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

 <img id="myImage" src="old_image.jpg" alt="Old Image">

 // Get the element by its ID
var image = document.getElementById("myImage");

function myFunction() {
  var option= document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  switch(option) {
    case "a":
    image.src = "new_image.jpg";
    break;
    case "b":
    image.src = "new_image_2.jpg";
    break;
    case "c":
    image.src = "new_image_3.jpg";
    break;
    default:
    image.src = "image.jpg";
  }
}
```